# How to use Custom Static UITableViewCells to display images in cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableview with 5 static cells.  They are static because there will always only be 5 of them in the tableview.

[image: Custom Cell]

I want them custom cells because I need to center UIImageViews in each cell because they will have button images and nothing else.  I created a MyCustomCell class with a UIImageView outlet and connected it to the outlet.

[image: Cell Xib]

Then in the tableview controller class I did this:

```
#pragma mark - TableView Cell Methods
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyCustomCell *cell = [[MyCustomCell alloc] init];

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            // Use Custom Cell
            cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"];
            break;
        case 1:
            [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
            // USE IMAGE INSTEAD
            cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button1.png"];
            break;
        case 2:
            cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button2.png"];
            break;
        case 3:
            cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button3.png"];
            break;
        case 4:
            cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Search.png"];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

MyCustomCell.m:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

The cells show up blank.  It worked fine when instead of MyCustomCell i was using UITableViewCell.  So Im not sure why its failing now.

Comment: post your CustomCell.m init method contents, or layoutSubviews. Also, you should be checking if a cell exists by dequeueing, otherwise you'll be allocating new cells every time a cell scrolls off screen (bad)

Comment: But these are static cells.

Comment: There's no reference to thumbnailImageView inside your custom cell class, where does this imageView get set up (init, frame etc)

Comment: You're not supposed to implement cellForRowAtIndexPath (or any other data source methods) when you use a static table view. Just add your subviews directly in the storyboard, and make outlets from the controller to the cells or directly to the subviews if you want. This is covered in Apple's documentation for table views.

Comment: @rdelmar Ok but if I add the images directly, how do I handle swappable images?  That is, how do I handle changing one image for another once the cell is tapped?

Comment: @marciokoko, you can still implement the delegate method, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: and swap them out using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anywhere where you reference the .xib file for your custom cell in `MyCustomCell.m`. You have to tell the class which .xib file to load.

Check out the following tutorial, which demonstrates one method to load the cell from the .xib file (within the custom cell class): [Creating custom UITableViewCell from XIBs – step by step tutorial](http://blog.spritebandits.com/2012/03/13/creating-custom-uitableviewcells-from-xibs-step-by-step-tutorial/)

This question shows another method (within `cellForRowAtIndexPath`):
[how to create custom tableViewCell from xib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195726/how-to-create-custom-tableviewcell-from-xib)

Also, you're not really using static cells if you're recreating them in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. You'll lose anything you've setup in Interface Builder. Consider abandoning the static cells. You can just setup all the cell properties in the same place you set the image.

Finally, if you do abandon the static cell approach consider creating your custom cell within the same view controller as your table view (the standard `UITableView` has a placeholder cell for this purpose) and dequeue the custom cell the standard way. Then, there is no additional .xib to load, so it will be handled automatically. See my previous answer for more details on [creating a custom table view cell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17839940/168493) like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using static cells, just create IBOutlets to each cell and then do something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     MyCustomCell *cell = nil;

    switch (indexPath.row) {
         case 0:
             cell0.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"];
             cell = cell0;
             break;
          case 1:
             //you can set the accessory type in the storyboard
             [cell1 setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
              cell1.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button1.png"];
             cell = cell1;
            break;
           //etc
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Ok I already did create the MyCustomCell class, added the UIImageView outlet and connected it, made each static cell of Identity MyCustomCell. But I omitted the cell = cell0 step. I just set it directly.  What do you mean by cell0?